# Does anyone know the Italian title of the poem "Stufen" from Hermann Hesse (en: Steps)?

Tags: translation

I am trying to find somewhere the Italian translation of the poem "Stufen" from Hermann Hesse (En:steps). I googled it several time and I cannot find anything!

Does anyone know what is it called in Italian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be "Gradini". [Here](https://sensodellavita.com/2008/07/01/gradini-hermann-hesse/) are the lycris in Italian.

Comment: Wow, how did you find it? I didn't come up with this possible translation of "Stufen", since it is poetry there are really tons of possible ways of expressing its meaning. I googled things like "passi" "fasi" "momenti" and I had no idea what else to do!

Comment: I googled https://www.google.de/search?q=hermann+hesse+stufen+italienisch